# Can we use webhooks using BigCommrce legacy API?

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I want to use product webhook on bigcommerce so that whenever a product gets added in Bigcommerce system it post back to an url with its details.
My question is can I use it using Legacy API (private app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From BigCommerce [WebHooks: Getting Started](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/webhooks-getting-started)

> PRO TIP: Webhooks differ from the rest of the Stores API as follows:
>   
> * OAuth is required: **Basic Authentication is not supported.**
>   
> * Self-signed certificates are not supported.
>   
> * JSON is required; XML is not supported.

The Legacy API and it's keys use Basic Auth, which is not supported. So unfortunately no, you cannot use WebHooks via the Legacy API.

You could possibly register a webhook using OAuth and have it's hook point to a URL that does work using the Legacy API, but if you're using OAuth with valid tokens, it kind of defeats the purpose of routing it to a Legacy App anyway. Save for an app too big or non-modular to be modified to fit OAuth.